# Why does this IQueryable issue give me an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iqueryable

I cannot figure out why code below is not working. It is causing a build error:

> `IQueryable<InventoryTbl>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.FirstOrDefault<AdminModel>(IQueryable<Admin>)`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RuciyanaSweets.Models;

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AdminAddorEdit(int id = 0)
{
    if (id==0)
        return View(new Model());
    else
    {
        using (Entities db = new Entities ())
        {
            return View(db.TableName.Where(x => x.FieldID == id).FirstOrDefault< Model >());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rayman Bacchus, to help you, you need to add a text of error message

Comment: @Rayman Bacchus: Can you add definition of the `TableName` to the post, please? It should be like `public virtual DbSet<Model> TableName { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The definition `TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)` is part of `System.Linq` namespace. Check that your project referencing to `System.Core` and you have `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Data.Entity;`.
- Be sure you installed the `EntityFramework` package.

[Queryable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I have both `using System.Linq` and `using System.Data.Entity` in my controller already.  In fact, they are in the controller and the model.

Comment: @Rayman Bacchus: From some reason compiler can't found the `FirstOrDefault()` definition. It can be because of: **1)** wrong assembly reference; **2)** type mismatch in your LINQ expression. Make the following: put caret on the `Where` extension method and press F12. Look at the first line of the file where the `Where()` is defined _(the `FirstOrDefault()` defined in the same assembly)_, to understand what assembly is implementing the `Where` extension method. It should be `System.Core`. Check if it is so?

Comment: Figured it out.  I was using an incorrect model apparently.  I can't explain why though.  I created my own model based off of the database and it did not work, but when I used the auto created model it worked.  Thanks for this thought - it pointed me in the direction of the wrong model being used.  I just can't figure out why one model worked and the other didn't and they are basically copies.  But that's going to be an investigation for another day.

Comment: @Rayman Bacchus: That's why in such cases it's suggested to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Glad you resolved the problem.